# Show/hide для трех блоков пошагово

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, плиз, начинающему.
Задача: Пошаговое переключение между тремя блоками по клику.
Шаг№1. клик по кнопке. блок с кнопкой исчезает. появляется блок с формой
Шаг№2. клик по кнопке в форме. форма исчезает. появляется блок с сообщением.

Проблема: кликнутые элементы исчезают, но новые не появляются(

Заранее спасибо!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

$('.sharebutton').click(function()
 {
  $('.start').hide();
  var form = $('.radioform').css('display') = 'block';
  $(form).toggle("fast");

 });
$('.send').click(function()
 {
  $('.radioform').hide();
  var message = $('.tellend').css('display') = 'block';
  $(message).toggle("fast");

 });



});
```

```css
.radioform {
   display:none;
  }
  
.tellend {
   display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

 
</head>
<body>

  
            <!--1st block. Button-->
              <div class="start">
               <span class="tell">Поделись!</span><br><br>
               <button class="sharebutton">Делиться!</button>
              </div>
             <!--2nd block. Form--> 
                    <form class="radioform">
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" checked>
                        через SMS

                      </label>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="+380"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio">
                        через E-mail
                      </label>
                    </div> <br>
                
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="send">Отправить</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    
               <!--3rd block. Message-->
               <span class="tellend">Спасибо что поделились!</span>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил только JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

$('.sharebutton').click(function()
 {
  $('.start').hide();
  var form = $('.radioform').css('display', 'block');
 });
$('.send').click(function()
 {
  $('.radioform').hide();
  var message = $('.tellend').css('display', 'block');

 });
});
```

```css
.radioform {
   display:none;
  }
  
.tellend {
   display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

 
</head>
<body>

  
            <!--1st block. Button-->
              <div class="start">
               <span class="tell">Поделись!</span><br><br>
               <button class="sharebutton">Делиться!</button>
              </div>
             <!--2nd block. Form--> 
                    <form class="radioform">
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" checked>
                        через SMS

                      </label>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="+380"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio">
                        через E-mail
                      </label>
                    </div> <br>
                
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="send">Отправить</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    
               <!--3rd block. Message-->
               <span class="tellend">Спасибо что поделились!</span>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо!
в боевой версии (полной верстке) все идеально.
в краткой версии, которую делала для вопроса, есть проблемка: третий блок .tellend появляется на секунду, сам исчезает, а потом видимо страница перезагружается на начало. чисто для развития - не подскажете почему так?

Comment: Но здесь такой проблемы нет? Я не понимаю в чём проблема. :)

Comment: ну типа для себя)

Comment: В смысле я не вижу описанной проблемы. Ничего не исчезает само. :) Демо можно?

Comment: это какая-то магея :) в сниппете работает, в полной версии моей верстки работает, а в укороченной - нет. ну и пёс с ней. еще раз спасибо за помощь!